# How to send UTF-8 coded XML without receiving umlauts in entity notation

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding, utf-8

I'm sending data to a business partner. The demand of the partner is clear: UTF-8 signed XML. Furthermore they want to receive german umlauts not being in entity notation.

This  [german site](http://www.gemeinde-michendorf.de/homepage/8sonstiges/entity.php)  tells it decimal notation. But it means the same.

So how to tell the Encoding how to send the umlauts?

Thanks in advance!

//edit: the business partner confirmed they receive the umlauts in entity notation (&#123)

//edit2: here's the code I use to send the data

```
WebClient client = new WebClient
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy("wwwproxy", 80)
    {
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    }
};
byte[] response = client.UploadData(
    Data.Resources.gateway_uri,
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)));

return XDocument.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response));
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use? As UTF.8 contains umlauts, there must be some conceptual mistake. What system receives the XML on 'their' part?

Comment: I've added some code. At the moment I don't know what system receives the data. Maybe I can find out next week.

Comment: The interesting part of the code is missing. You'll need to provide more information about `request`. What type is it and how do you create it?

Comment: Isn't `&#123;` an open brace? As Codo says, more information would be useful.

Comment: request is a System.Xml.Linq.XDocument including the data, signature and so on. If I save the document on my hardddisk everything looks fine. Most time I work with the XDocument. Just for generating the signature I use System.Xml.XmlDocument

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `request` is an `XNode` instance and I'm guessing that its `ToString` method tries to avoid encoding problems by encoding most characters outside the ASCII range as it cannot know what the final encoding will be.

To have better control over the encoding, you'll need to use an XML writer with a stream:

```
MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // should be the default, but you never know
XMLWriter writer = XMLWriter.Create(buffer, settings);
request.WriteTo(writer);
writer.Flush();
byte[] requestData = buffer.ToArray();
byte[] response = client.UploadData(Data.Resources.gateway_uri, requestData);
```